# Chart control reverse y axis but keep x axis at bottom

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mschart

Please refer to this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQh6D.jpg

As you can see whenever I reverse Y axis the X axis moves to top. Is there anyway I can reverse Y axis and keep X at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
series.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
```

It worked for me